# Login Issue ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis

I was having an issue with permissions on one of my .NET applications. I added the following line to the webconfig and things started to go wrong.

```
<add key="authenticator.login_page" value="login.aspx" />
```

I took the line away, and now, cant login with any of my users. I tried adding users to Website/ASP.Net configuration and got the following error.

```
Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE'
```

I gave this user permissions to the applications database, which got rid of the above error, but cant add users in Website/ASP.Net configuration anymore,

```
Cannot open user default database. Login failed. Login failed for user 'HOST\user'.
```

and the application is just showing our custom 'user cannot login' message.

Anyone know what I should look out for.

Mark

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many things might be wrong but it sounds like you want to use forms authentication?  If so have you this in your web.config?

```
<authentication  mode="Forms">
```

If is possible you wish to impersonate

```
<identity impersonate="true"/>
```

However, there are many factors at play here and I would recommend taking a little time to read up on these before simply adding by guesswork

Comment: that tag is there. <authentication mode="Forms" />. We werent using the Website/ASP.Net configuration before today. I was hoping using that would help regain access to my accounts. We had a custom user admin inside the app. Would the above tag be causing the problem. I think i may have added NT authentication by mistake locally on the config file and now copied over the live server....backup, backup, backup. :-/

Comment: @madphp backup?  you not got source control?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you have an custom form authentication module which uses the authenticator.login_page key and that fails if you remove the key, is that possible ?

Otherwise you should check the web.config settings and be sure that the application is running under the correct credentials, you can take a look at [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302377.aspx) to see how the credentials are determined.

You should also check in your web.config if  attributes are correct for your scenario, this is what usually redirects users to the login page as you can see in the following picture

[alt text http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/Aa480476.formsauth(en-us,MSDN.10).gif](http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/Aa480476.formsauth(en-us,MSDN.10).gif)

Also how are you connecting to the database, do you have a sql server user that is used for database connections, or is the application credentials used ? In the latter case the user might not have correct permissions to access the database

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the webapp pool account has access.